# Checkmark accepted at all 23 countries at the same place. But how can I set it for one place

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkmark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lofm1.jpg)[image]I have two `UITableView`s: one with countries and other with coins. When I select a country I can see inside the amount of coins of that country. When I tap the amount of coins, a checkmark is filled out as checked. But the checkmark is marking all the 23 countries when a single country coins item is tapped.

How can I switch to checked only the country being tapped?

//the first TableView (countries)

```
import UIKit

class MainUITableViewController: UITableViewController {

var flagName = [
    "Andorra",
    "Austria",
    "Belgium",
    "Cyprus",
    "Estonia",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "Germany",
    "Greece",
    "Ireland",
    "Italy",
    "Latvia",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Malta",
    "Monaco",
    "Netherlands",
    "Portugal",
    "San_Marino",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Spain",
    "Vatican_City"]

var flagImage = [
    "Andorra",
    "Austria",
    "Belgium",
    "Cyprus",
    "Estonia",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "Germany",
    "Greece",
    "Ireland",
    "Italy",
    "Latvia",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Malta",
    "Monaco",
    "Netherlands",
    "Portugal",
    "San_Marino",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Spain",
    "Vatican_City"]

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.destinationViewController is SecondUITableViewController {

        let second_vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondUITableViewController
        second_vc.current_index = (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!

    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return flagName.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ComponentsUITableViewCell

    cell.flagImageView?.image = UIImage(named: flagImage[indexPath.row])
    cell.nameInCell?.text = flagName[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

}
```

// the second TableView (coins)

```
import UIKit

class SecondUITableViewController: UITableViewController {

var coinsNames = ["1 euro cent", "2 euro cent", "5 euro cent", "10 euro cent", "20 euro cent", "50 euro cent", "1 euro", "2 euro"]
var coinsImageA = ["Andorra_1", "Andorra_2", "Andorra_5", "Andorra_10", "Andorra_20", "Andorra_50", "Andorra_1e", "Andorra_2e"]
var coinsImageB = ["Austria_1", "Austria_2", "Austria_5", "Austria_10", "Austria_20", "Austria_50", "Austria_1e", "Austria_2e"]
var coinsImageC = ["Belgium_1", "Belgium_2", "Belgium_5", "Belgium_10", "Belgium_20", "Belgium_50", "Belgium_1e", "Belgium_2e"]
var coinsImageD = ["Cyprus_1", "Cyprus_2", "Cyprus_5", "Cyprus_10", "Cyprus_20", "Cyprus_50", "Cyprus_1e", "Cyprus_2e"]
var coinsImageE = ["Estonia_1", "Estonia_2", "Estonia_5", "Estonia_10", "Estonia_20", "Estonia_50", "Estonia_1e", "Estonia_2e"]
var coinsImageF = ["Finland_1", "Finland_2", "Finland_5", "Finland_10", "Finland_20", "Finland_50", "Finland_1e", "Finland_2e"]
var coinsImageG = ["France_1", "France_2", "France_5", "France_10", "France_20", "France_50", "France_1e", "France_2e"]
var coinsImageH = ["Germany_1", "Germany_2", "Germany_5", "Germany_10", "Germany_20", "Germany_50", "Germany_1e", "Germany_2e"]
var coinsImageI = ["Greece_1", "Greece_2", "Greece_5", "Greece_10", "Greece_20", "Greece_50", "Greece_1e", "Greece_2e"]
var coinsImageJ = ["Ireland_1", "Ireland_2", "Ireland_5", "Ireland_10", "Ireland_20", "Ireland_50", "Ireland_1e", "Ireland_2e"]
var coinsImageK = ["Italy_1", "Italy_2", "Italy_5", "Italy_10", "Italy_20", "Italy_50", "Italy_1e", "Italy_2e"]
var coinsImageL = ["Latvia_1", "Latvia_2", "Latvia_5", "Latvia_10", "Latvia_20", "Latvia_50", "Latvia_1e", "Latvia_2e"]
var coinsImageM = ["Lithuania_1", "Lithuania_2", "Lithuania_5", "Lithuania_10", "Lithuania_20", "Lithuania_50", "Lithuania_1e", "Lithuania_2e"]
var coinsImageN = ["Luxembourg_1", "Luxembourg_2", "Luxembourg_5", "Luxembourg_10", "Luxembourg_20", "Luxembourg_50", "Luxembourg_1e", "Luxembourg_2e"]
var coinsImageO = ["Malta_1", "Malta_2", "Malta_5", "Malta_10", "Malta_20", "Malta_50", "Malta_1e", "Malta_2e"]
var coinsImageP = ["Monaco_1", "Monaco_2", "Monaco_5", "Monaco_10", "Monaco_20", "Monaco_50", "Monaco_1e", "Monaco_2e"]
var coinsImageQ = ["Netherlands_1", "Netherlands_2", "Netherlands_5", "Netherlands_10", "Netherlands_20", "Netherlands_50", "Netherlands_1e", "Netherlands_2e"]
var coinsImageR = ["Portugal_1", "Portugal_2", "Portugal_5", "Portugal_10", "Portugal_20", "Portugal_50", "Portugal_1e", "Portugal_2e"]
var coinsImageS = ["San_Marino_1", "San_Marino_2", "San_Marino_5", "San_Marino_10", "San_Marino_20", "San_Marino_50", "San_Marino_1e", "San_Marino_2e"]
var coinsImageT = ["Slovakia_1", "Slovakia_2", "Slovakia_5", "Slovakia_10", "Slovakia_20", "Slovakia_50", "Slovakia_1e", "Slovakia_2e"]
var coinsImageU = ["Slovenia_1", "Slovenia_2", "Slovenia_5", "Slovenia_10", "Slovenia_20", "Slovenia_50", "Slovenia_1e", "Slovenia_2e"]
var coinsImageV = ["Spain_1", "Spain_2", "Spain_5", "Spain_10", "Spain_20", "Spain_50", "Spain_1e", "Spain_2e"]
var coinsImageW = ["Vatican_City_1", "Vatican_City_2", "Vatican_City_5", "Vatican_City_10", "Vatican_City_20", "Vatican_City_50", "Vatican_City_1e", "Vatican_City_2e"]

var current_index = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return coinsNames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Components2UITableViewCell

    cell2.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    switch current_index {

    case 0:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageA[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 1:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageB[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 2:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageC[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 3:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageD[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 4:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageE[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 5:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageF[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 6:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageG[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 7:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageH[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 8:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageI[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 9:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageJ[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 10:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageK[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 11:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageL[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 12:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageM[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 13:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageN[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 14:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageO[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 15:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageP[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 16:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageQ[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 17:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageR[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 18:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageS[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 19:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageT[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 20:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageU[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 21:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageV[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    case 22:
        cell2.coinsImageView?.image = UIImage(named: coinsImageW[indexPath.row])
        cell2.cionsName?.text = coinsNames[indexPath.row]

        default: cell2

    }

    cell2.accessoryType = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(coinsNames[indexPath.row]) == true ? .Checkmark : .None
    return cell2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //        self.coinsNames[indexPath.row]
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(!NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(coinsNames[indexPath.row]), forKey: coinsNames[indexPath.row])
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
}

}
```

Comment: You missed the seccond tableview code.

Comment: Please, provide the snippet for the NSUserDefaults booleans first assignments, the provided code only makes use of values that have already been added to it.

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you to make a tuple like that:

```
typealias yourItem = (flagName: String, flagImage: String, selected: Bool)
```

Then change your tableView **dataSource** to array of `[yourItem]` like

`let tableData: [yourItem] = [yourItem(), yourItem()....]`

Finally in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** you should check the selected state like that

```
let item = tableData[indexPath.row]
cell.accessoryView = item.selected ? .Checkmark : nil
```

Comment: Types and therefore typealiases should be pascal cased.

Answer (score 0):

You must be initiallizing `NSUserDefaults` booleans with true, making the first rendering of the `UITableView` (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`) to set all accesories to `.Checkmark`:

```
cell2.accessoryType = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(coinsNames[indexPath.row]) == true ? .Checkmark : .None
```

Check where you first set the `NSUserDefaults` booleans to verify whether they are being initiallized with `true` or not.

If not, proceed with the check on all `NSUserDefaults` assignments throughout the application.

You should be able to find where the problem is with this procedure, once the only place you are switching the accesory - as per the snippet - is at the aforementioned line.

Providing all `NSUserDefaults` assignments in the application would help us come up with a more precise answer.

It seems that you are not initializing NSUserDefaults bools prior to make use of it, try to iterate through the coinsNames arrays and set the NSUserDefault value to false on each key:

```
for coinName in coinsNames {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, coinName)
}
```

Comment: andriosr! I recently added a photo. Did you mean this ?

Comment: No, the code you provided (including the image) makes use of NSUserDefaults 3 times:

Comment: Actually twice: 1) get the accessory type in cellForRowAtIndexPath;  2) set what is already there for a given key and synchronize it when tapped (didSelectRowAtIndexPath). But where do you first set the values for the keys? What do you expect to be the value for a given key that hasn't been tapped at cellForRowAtIndexPath? Did you put anything there before using it?

Comment: andriosr, could you please download this at github. I'm learning SWIFT for about 1 month and made this program watching different youtube videos.https://github.com/SCherkasov/Stasik/blob/master/***888***.zip and bad understand what you mean

Comment: Ok, so it seems that you are not initializing the NSUserDefaults bool values. Try to iterate trough coinsNames and  set all keys to false before loading the tableview. Added this hint to the answer